# Is there any option to replace NVL in where clause for parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have been using NVL in my WHERE clause and it worked well till now.
But in such case where the column has NULL value and parameter was also NULL, it didnt return any query.

```
select * from Table
where
f_date BETWEEN NVL(:F_DATE_FROM,F_DATE) AND NVL(:F_DATE_TO,F_DATE)
AND op_code = NVL(:CODE, OP_CODE) 
AND T_CBC = NVL(:TO_CBC,T_CBC)
order by fiscal_date desc
```

I updated the query as below, and it returns me all the records as expected. However it takes way too long to execute the query. The original query took 1.5min and the new query takes 7min. Is there any way to fine tune the below query please?

```
select * from Table
where
f_date BETWEEN NVL(:F_DATE_FROM,F_DATE) AND NVL(:F_DATE_TO,F_DATE)
AND (OP_CODE = :CODE or :CODE is null) 
AND (T_CBC = :TO_CBC or :TO_CBC is null)
order by fiscal_date desc
```

Comment: The queries are doing different things.  If a lot of the data values are `NULL`, then including those will have a large impact on performance.

Comment: What should be the result if the column value is NULL? If you want to include it, you could refactor your conditions to something like 
`(column IS NULL or column = nvl(column, param))`

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
WHERE 
  (f_date >= :F_DATE_FROM OR :F_DATE_FROM IS NULL) AND
  (f_date <= :F_DATE_TO OR :F_DATE_TO IS NULL) AND
  ...
```

though I'm not sure how much of a performance improvement it'll realize. If your query is about performance specifically, ask a question that includes a query plan